# On Ctrl-d, call Close() like with file objects happen

Tags: python, multithreading, command-line, eof

I've [wrote a class](https://github.com/srgblnch/scpi/blob/master/scpi/scpi.py) that inherits from *object* and has instances of sub-objects that uses some *threads* for tasks. There are two socket *listeners* that creates other threads for each *accept*ed connection. They do what they have to do. To finish them, they are looking on a *Threading.Event* object to know that they have to finish.

I've noticed that, when exit the python console they are not notified (or don't catch the notification) and the exit don't return control to the bash console, unless a *Close()* is called before.

First idea to fix it has been to implement the *'__del__'* method to use the garbage collector to clean it when exit.

```py
class ServiceProvider(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ServiceProvider,self).__init__()
        #...
        self.Open()
    def Open(self):
        #... Some threads are created.
    def Close(self):
        #.... Threading.Event to report the threads to finish
    def __del__(self):
        self.Close()
```

But the behaviour is the same. If I place a print in those methods, non in *'__del__'*, neither in *'Close'* they are written. Unless it is closed before, then the print in the *del* is wrote.

Then I've implemented the *'__enter__'* and *'__exit__'* methods to manage the *with* statement. And the *exit* behaves as expected and when the *with* ends, things are release. But what I really want is to have something like the *file descriptors* that event if *file.close()* is not called, it is executed when exits the program.

```py
class ServiceProvider(object):
    #...
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self):
        self.Close()
```

Searching for more solutions I've tried with [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) but not. I have similar results that doesn't fix the issue. Even I collect all the objects created of this class, the *doOnExit* only writes its print if the objects in the list are already *Close*.

```py
import atexit
global objects2Close
objects2Close = []

@atexit.register
def doOnExit():
    for obj in objects2Close:
        obj.Close()

class ServiceProvider(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ServiceProvider,self).__init__()
        objects2Close.append(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution for this issue. The posted information in this question was not related with the real issue.

This is as simple as daemon threading.

A the implementation uses some threads for listening remote connections they have to finish their execution when the program goes to exit. But the program ends when all the *[no daemon](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon)* thread has finished.

Mistakenly those listeners and talkers where not set to be *daemons* and that's why the execution waits for them.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a good idea to use `with` when you have resources that you don't want to leak (files, connections, whatever else you care about).

Somewhere, just outside your main loop you should have something like:

```
with ServiceProvider(some_params) as service_provider:
  rest_of_the_code()
```

What this does is that regardless of how you exit rest_of_the_code() (except for kill -9) it will call service_provider.Close() at the end. This works for exceptions and interrupts as well. Kill -9 doesn't work because the process is kill at os level and doesn't have a chance to attempt to recover.

Comment: Yes, and it works fine this way. For code that uses the library should be used this way, But creating an object of this class in a python console, one will lose the nice interaction to explore how it works. I don't like to deliver something that requires a *ctrl-z* and a *kill* when used from console.